# AWS s3 download callback

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, laravel-4, amazon-s3, callback

Is it possible to setup a callback on completion of a download of an object from a S3 bucket?  I've looked through the code and see some callbacks for upload and delete,  I need to increment a counter when the object is downloaded - I'd like some guarantee that they've downloaded it instead of incrementing the counter BEFORE the download starts.

**UPDATE**

```
$s3 = App::make('aws')->get('s3');

if($s3->doesObjectExist('bucket', $url)) {
    return $s3->getObjectUrl('bucket', $url, time() + 500);
}
```

Currently, the returned object URL is being used in a redirect. Web app is being created w/ Laravel.

Comment: what code are you using now?

Comment: AWS PHP SDK

http://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/

Comment: I'm wondering what _your_ code looks like though. I might be able to help you out, but I'm not sure what you have done already.

Comment: Added some code - its pretty rudimentary right now since we're not sure if this is possible or how to do it.